# I can not deploy EAR to Glassfish 4.1

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ear

I create JavaEE app EAR=EJB+WAR
[image]

Project compile:

```
[INFO] QCforCC-main ...................................... SUCCESS [0.407s]
[INFO] QCforCC-ejb ....................................... SUCCESS [4.424s]
[INFO] QCforCC-war ....................................... SUCCESS [2.644s]
[INFO] QCforCC-ear ....................................... SUCCESS [1.478s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.081s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Oct 08 13:45:05 ALMT 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 26M/406M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

But when I deploy i get an error:

```
Connected to server
[2015-10-08 01:46:20,210] Artifact QCforCC-ear:ear exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2015-10-08 01:46:20,210] Artifact QCforCC-ear:ear exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [QCforCC-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT] : Expected to find an expanded directory for submodule QCforCC-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar but found a JAR.  If this is a directory deployment be sure to expand all submodules.. Please see server.log for more details.
```

My EAR look like
[image]

And if i open EAR in Archive:

[image]

My POM.XML of EAR module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>QCforCC-main</artifactId>
        <groupId>QCforCC-main</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>QCforCC-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>

    <name>QCforCC-ear</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>QCforCC-main</groupId>
        <artifactId>QCforCC-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>QCforCC-main</groupId>
        <artifactId>QCforCC-war</artifactId>
        <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <modules>
                        <ejbModule>
                            <groupId>QCforCC-main</groupId>
                            <artifactId>QCforCC-ejb</artifactId>
                        </ejbModule>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>QCforCC-main</groupId>
                            <artifactId>QCforCC-war</artifactId>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

What I do wrong? I have EAR artefact but can not deploy it

Comment: Why has your EAR the extension RAR?

Comment: I make it that open in winrar. Original file .ear. Look in screens

Comment: I can see that, but the filename extension doesn't change by opening something through winrar.

Comment: so I changed. I say the same to open with winrar.this is not important now. I'm not this file deploy

Comment: How are you doing your deployment? Can you add a list of steps?